# Check if existing username from controller and redirect to view page if already exists

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I have the following username lookup function that checks if the username is available.

```
<script language="javascript">
function lookUpUsername(){
    var name = document.getElementById('username').value;
    //alert(name);
    $.post( 
        'users/ajax_lookUpUsername',
        { username: name },
        function(response) {  
            if (response == 1) {
                //  alert('username available');
            } else {
                // setTimeout("alert("Here I am!")", 5000);
                alert('Username Already Taken! Please Select Another Name.');
            }
        }); 
    }
</script>
```

And here is my AJAX_lookUpUsername function in the controller:

```
function ajax_lookUpUsername(){
    $username = $this->input->post('username');
    $this->db->where('username', $username);
    $query = $this->db->get('mcb_users');
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
        echo 0;
    } else {
        echo 1;
    }
```

The code works fine. When a user enters an existing username, it displays an alert message, but, when a user continues without modifying it and clicks on the save button, it gets saved!

Is there any way to redirect the user before saving to the database from the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using `onsubmit` form validation also. But, there is another approach too.
You can do this through controller also. Add the following code in save function of your controller, just before inserting data to database:

```
    $userarraydb = $this->mdl_users->getAllusername();
    foreach($userarraydb as $dbusersname)
    {
        if(($dbusersname->text == $username) && ($dbusersname->id != $user_id) )
        {   
            //echo $this->lang->line('user_name_must_be_unique');
            //sleep(1);
        ?>  <script> alert('Record can not be saved! Username must be unique.'); </script> <?php
            return false;

        }


    }
```

and add following function to your user model:

```
function getAllusername()
    {
        $teller_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');   
        $this->db->select('username as text, id as id');
        $this->db->from('mcb_users'); 
        $result = $this->db->get();
        $username = $result->result();
        //all user name taneko cha
        return $username;
    //  return $result->result();

    }
```

Comment: Thank you veekay . This really worked. I had been stuck since hours. Saved my time really thankful to you.